# Changing locale but staying on the current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I did an internationalization of my website.
I used https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator

Every link are working depending on the current locale

I have 2 buttons like this :  EN | FR

You can click on it to change the locale. It's working like this :

```
  if I18n.locale == :fr
    link_to('en', root_en_path)
  else
    link_to('fr', root_fr_path)
  end
```

The only problem is that if I'm on a certain page in my website and I change the locale, it will comeback to the root_path

What I want is to stay on the same page.

For example: I have a how_it_works page

If I'm in `/fr/how_it_works` I want the `EN` button to link to `/en/how_it_works`

I've been told to pass the locale as a param but I don't want that because I don't want to have a big link like `/fr/how_it_works?locale=en` and I'm sure that's a bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found a basic way to do it. I first thought this thing was already implemented in route_translator, but apparently no.

The solution :

```
  if I18n.locale == :fr
    en_uri = request.fullpath.gsub('/fr', '/en')
    good_link = en_uri[0, 3] == '/en' ? en_uri : root_en_path
    link_to('en', good_link)
  else
    fr_uri = request.fullpath.gsub('/en', '/fr')
    good_link = fr_uri[0, 3] == '/fr' ? fr_uri : root_fr_path
    link_to('fr', good_link)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The advice you were given would be the best approach and no, you wouldn't be using a query parameter as you thought.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ':locale', constraints: { locale: /(en|fr)/ } do
   #define all your scopeable routes within here
  end
end
```

This way, you can visit `/en/how-it-works` or `/fr/how-it-works`. In your ApplicationController, you can do a `before action :set_locale` where you'd be setting the locale as `params[:locale]`.

Hope that makes it clearer and resolves your issue.

**UPDATE**

Can't really figure out a better way of achieving this, but here's a way I could immediately work out:

```
url_params = params.to_h
if I18n.locale == :fr
  link_to('en', url_params.merge(locale: :en))
else
  link_to('fr', url_params.merge(locale: :fr)
end
```

Comment: I can already visit those links, this is not the problem. The problem is I don't know how to call the current page/path like this `/fr/current_path`

Answer (score 1):

Thank good lord for bringing the solution to me! I've just encountered you guys having the same issue so here it is what I have used.

```
<%= link_to(options = {controller: controller_name, action: action_name, locale: :en} , class: "navbar-item") do %>
    <%= image_tag "gb.svg", size: "24x24" %>
<% end %>
```

For displaying a link to the same page, however changing locales and using an image as link.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar setup, and came across this (old) question. Matheus answer helped me to order my thoughts, and for me the solution was as simple as

```rb
<%= link_to "fr", controller: controller_name, action: action_name, locale: "fr"  %>
```

---

Note that this works because I use "scope" in routes.rb:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/ do
  ...
end
```

This way, the locale gets passed on every request, and fetching it is easy

```
  I18n.locale = params[:locale]
```

I wanted to share this for others who might come by. Once again, built in rails comes with the power to do amazing things with a few lines.

Happy codin .

Answer (score -1):

What about ? :

```
<%= link_to "English", current_page_params.merge(locale: :en) %>
```

See more about it : https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-link-to-current-page-with-params

Comment: `current_page_params`  is not a valid variable.

Comment: Seems like this answer uses an approach from https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-link-to-current-page-with-params

Comment: I've watched the episode, and it has little to do with what OP asked for. Actually, I assume this answer is based on a 5 second (max) online search and little knowledge about the rails framework. -1